# Subsetting a R data.table with a function call: How to return a vector of results instead of just one result?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to subset a data.table based on a function that I wrote.

I have found out that R only calls my function once (instead of once per row). However, I am having trouple debugging this as I can only address Date in the context of the data.table.

For runtime purposes, I cannot use a for-loop to check each row individually.
If this problem could be solved without a self-defined function, I would be happy, too.

```r
library("data.table")
library("zoo")

dt <- data.table(Date = as.Date(1:10),
                 Sales = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5)))
anySalesLastWeek <- function(date) {
  return(!empty(dt[as.integer(Date - as.Date(date)) %in% -7:-1 & Sales > 0, ]))
}
dt[anySalesLastWeek(Date), ]
```

I expected R to call the function anySalesLastWeek() once per row with the column value of Date in that row. Instead, the function seems to be called only once with dt$Date as the input.

The expected output would be the first six rows.

Comment: what are you trying to detect with your function? do you mind explaining in words?

Comment: Of course. I want to find out whether for a given date, there have been any sales in the last week.

Edit: Therefore, I check if there is a row with non-zero Sales in dt with Date (the column value in that row) seven to one days prior to the argument date.

Comment: Try `dt[sapply(Date,anySalesLastWeek),]`

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your criteria for row selection. Row 1 is selected because ... ?

Comment: Thank you, @Rohit, that approach works (and I should've come up with it myself).

However, I am still confused as to why something like `dt[is.Date(Date), ]` works but `dt[anySalesLastWeek(Date), ]` does not. I don't need to use `dt[sapply(Date, is.Date), ]`.

Comment: @NiklasvM, `is.Date` is vectorised. It takes the whole Date column as a vector input and returns a logical vector output of the same length. If you don't want to use `sapply`, ensure that your function is designed for the entire column, not just one entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood it correctly. Here is an approach using non-equi join:

```
DT[, oneweekago := Date - 7]
DT[, anySalesLastWeek := 
    DT[DT, on=.(Date>=oneweekago, Date<Date), allow.cartesian=TRUE, 
        sum(Sales, na.rm=TRUE) > 0, by=.EACHI]$V1
]
```

output:

```
          Date Sales oneweekago anySalesLastWeek
 1: 2019-10-04     0 2019-09-27            FALSE
 2: 2019-10-05     0 2019-09-28            FALSE
 3: 2019-10-06     0 2019-09-29            FALSE
 4: 2019-10-07     0 2019-09-30            FALSE
 5: 2019-10-08     0 2019-10-01            FALSE
 6: 2019-10-09     1 2019-10-02            FALSE
 7: 2019-10-10     1 2019-10-03             TRUE
 8: 2019-10-11     1 2019-10-04             TRUE
 9: 2019-10-12     1 2019-10-05             TRUE
10: 2019-10-13     1 2019-10-06             TRUE
```

data:

```
library("data.table")
DT <- data.table(Date=seq(Sys.Date(), by="1 day", length.out=10), Sales=c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5)))

#          Date Sales
# 1: 2019-10-04     0
# 2: 2019-10-05     0
# 3: 2019-10-06     0
# 4: 2019-10-07     0
# 5: 2019-10-08     0
# 6: 2019-10-09     1
# 7: 2019-10-10     1
# 8: 2019-10-11     1
# 9: 2019-10-12     1
#10: 2019-10-13     1
```

---

edit: regarding OP's function and also from Rohit comment, you can fix it as follows:

```
anySalesLastWeek <- function(date) {
    DT[as.integer(Date - as.Date(date)) %in% -7:-1 & Sales > 0, .N>0]
}
DT[sapply(Date, anySalesLastWeek)]
```

Comment: Thank you, your first approach works just the way I want to.

However, I am still confused as to why something like dt[is.Date(Date), ] works but dt[anySalesLastWeek(Date), ] does not.

Comment: you are comparing a row date against all `Date`s, hence you need `sapply` to apply on each element (row date) in the vector (`Date`)